# What kind of web filter is in web flux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

What kind of web filter is in web flux. I found only couple line about HandlerFilterFunction but in function mode. Is it right solution and does anyone have an example based on annotations.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the Spring WebFlux functional model provides `HandlerFilterFunction` (for both client and server).

If you're looking for Servlet-like filters, Spring WebFlux provides `org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter` and `org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain`.

Comment: Thanks, it was very easy.  Is it possible to map WebFilter to some resource or it should be done inside filter by internal logic?

Comment: There's no filter mapping with patterns mechanism, if that's what you're asking. So that part would need to be done internally.